# Get specific sidebars $wp_registered_sidebars

Tags: sidebar, child-theme

I've got the following functions as in this pastebin in a child theme:

> http://pastebin.com/uzjmXiyN

This functions creates a drop down box from where you can choose a sidebar for use on a specific page. Everything works fine after a lot of sweat. My only problem is the

> $wp_registered_sidebars

function in the following piece of code

```
foreach($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar)
{
    $output .= "<option";
    if($sidebar_id == $val)
        $output .= " selected='selected'";
    $output .= " value='".$sidebar_id."'>".$sidebar['name']."</option>";
}

$output .= "</select>";

echo $output;
```

This function lists all the available sidebars of the theme, and this is what I don't want. I only want the drop down box to display the sidebars in the

> $dynamic_widget_areas

array. If I replace

> $wp_registered_sidebars

with

> $dynamic_widget_areas

I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dynamic_widget_area ...etc

and

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  ...etc

What is the correct way to display only certain sidebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic PHP question. You need to check whether the `$sidebar_id` key is set in `$dynamic_widget_areas` as you loop through. This proof of concept code should give you the idea.

```
$dynamic_widget_areas = array(
  'sidebar-1' => 'stuff',
);
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
$output = '';
foreach($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar) {
  $output .= "<option";
  if(isset($dynamic_widget_areas[$sidebar_id])) {
     if($sidebar_id == $val) {
      $output .= " selected='selected'";
    }
    $output .= " value='".$sidebar_id."'>".$sidebar['name']."</option>";
  }
}
$output .= "</select>";
```